# Find $f$ if $f''(t)=2e^t+3\sin(t)$, $f(0)=-3$, and $f(\pi)=-7$

Tags: calculus, integration

What's the best way to approach the following problem?

> Find $f$ if $f''(t)=2e^t+3\sin(t)$, $f(0)=-3$, and $f(\pi)=-7$.

Previously when doing this sort of problem we'd be given some information about the next integral so we could solve for the constant $C$ that's added at each stage of integration.

**eg:** We'd have a question of the form

> Find $f$ if $f'(t) = \cos(t)$ and $f(\pi)=1$

With this we could integrate and get $f(t)=\sin(t)+C$, then use the information to set up $\sin(\pi)+C=1$ to find $C=1$.

Since in this question there is a "gap in the information given" so to speak, I'm stuck with a constant floating around that makes it really messy if I try and integrate a second time (in order to get from $f''$ to $f$).

Comment: The second integral really just has $+Cx+D$ on the end after the other terms, right?  What is it that makes this so messy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the formula for $ f '' $ we calculate:

$$  f'(t) = 2e^t - 3 \cos(t) + C$$

and therefore

$$ f(t) = 2e^t - 3\sin(t) + Ct + D $$

So now all you need to do is solve the system of equations:

$$ f(0) = 2 + D = -3 $$
$$ f(\pi) = 2e^\pi + C\pi + D = -7$$